# AJAX not working on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, click

83.238.171.65/przemyt/

login: tester

pass: tester

(not working good in Firefox and IE, i'll fix that)

Look at chat. When I send message first time everything working. But when I send second time sudenly  i'm fowarded to chat.php.

Code (you can also see it at debuging):

```
$(function() { 
$(document).ajaxError(function() { 
    alert('Sending error!'); 
});   
$('.chater').submit(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $this.attr('action'),
        data: $this.serialize(),

        success : function() {
            $('div.chat').load('chat.php');           
        },

        error : function() {
            alert('Conection error!');
        }                       
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with : `async:false;` ?